# TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData con el metódo $.post()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap

En consola me muestra este error. No consigo subir un fichero a un servidor utilizando modales con php y el metódo $.post.

El modals sería este incluido en index:

```
<div class="modal fade addModal" id="addModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="group">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title"></h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <?php include 'new_version.php'; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">                        
                <div id="operations">
                    <form class="add-form-modal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <button class="fa fa-edit btn btn-success"> Guardar</button>
                        <button type="button" class="fa fa-ban btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"> Ignorar</button>
                    </form>
                </div> 
            </div>                        
            <div id="infoAdd">
            </div>                     
            <div id="errorsAdd">
            </div>                     
        </div>
    </div>               
</div>
```

El div que recoge la imágen es este:

```
<div class="custom-file target_file">
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="data" name="data" value="<?php echo $versionfile->target_file ?>" required="">
    <label class="custom-file-label" for="data"> Seleccionar archivo ... </label>
</div>
```

Y el ajax es este:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.add-form-modal').submit(processFormAdd);
//
            function processFormAdd() {
                //Stop form from submitting normally
                event.preventDefault();

                target_name = $("#newtarget_name").val();
                disabled = $("#newdisabled").val();
                iduser = $("#newiduser").val();
                modificatedate = $("#newmodificatedate").val();

                var frmData = new FormData(this);
                var files = $("#data")[0].files[0];
                frmData.append('file', files);

                var url = "<?php echo url_for('/views/staff/docum/new_version.php?iddoc='); ?>" + iddoc;
                // hay que mirar la BBDD como se llaman las columnas (o en admin.class.php)
                var options = {'idfile': iddoc, 'target_name': target_name, 'disabled': disabled, 'iduser': iduser, 'modificatedate': modificatedate, 'target_file': frmData};

                // Send the data using post
                var posting = $.post(url, options);
                // Put the results in a div
                posting.done(function (data, textStatus, jQxhr) {
                    alert("Ajax success data perform " + data);
                    $('#errorsAdd').html('<div class="alert alert-success"> Información añadida con exito </div>').delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");

                    $('.add-form-modal')[0].reset();
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        location.reload();
                    }, 3000);

                }).fail(function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $('#info').html('<div class="alert alert-error"> Error al procesar la información </div>').fadeOut(5000);
                    alert("Ajax show throws: " + errorThrown);
                    if (console && console.log) {
                        console.log("La solicitud a fallado: " + textStatus);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Pero me muestra ese error y no consigo de ningún modo de subir el fichero. Por internet encontré que con el metódo **$.ajax** se tiene que añadir **proccessData:false** pero aquí como se hace?

De mencionar que anteriormente tenia toda la app solo php y me funcionaba, me subia el fichero al servidor.

Gracias de antemano. Saludos

Comment: No estás definiendo el objeto, antes de usarlo tienes que hacer algo así: **`var formData = new FormData();`**

Comment: Se me ha olvidado añadirlo a este post, lo tengo más arriba donde defino todas las variables. Lo defino de este modo: var formData = new FormData(); tal como me mencionas. Gracias

Comment: ¿Más arriba dónde? Pon el código completo para poder ayudarte mejor. El error lo que dice es que tu variable `formData` no implementa la interfaz `FormData`, lo que hace pensar que no está declarado adecuadamente o que o está puesto en el contexto de forma correcta. Pulsa en [edit] y pon el código en su estado real. Gracias.

Comment: Ya lo he editado, está fuera de todas las funciones

Comment: Revisa la respuesta. Prueba así y nos comentas.

Answer (score 1):

El objeto `formData` tiene que estar definido correctamente y estar en el contexto correctamente:

```
var formData=new FormData();
```

Luego, puedes declarar tu llamada de este modo, para poder pasarle el `processData: false`. Además, es recomendable también ponerle un `contentType: false`([ver esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8244082/5587982)).

Ejemplo:

```
function processFormAdd() {
    // ... código ....

    //Lo declaramos en el contexto de la función
    var formData = new FormData();

    //Es mejor definir una llamada Ajax del tipo POST
    var posting = $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'POST',
        data: formData, //Ojo a esto
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
    });

    // ... código ....
}
```

Otra cosa que no se entiende es por qué pasas `group` como data ¿? Si quieres pasar el `formData` incluyendo el contenido de `group` debes hacer `formData.append(group);`.

Comment: He probado muchas cosas que encontré por internet y todas con el mismo error. Ya no se que hacerle.

Comment: const inputFile = document.getElementById("data");
 var file = inputFile.files[0];
 let formData = new FormData();
 formData.append('data', file); // En la posición 0; es decir, el primer elemento
var url = "<?php echo url_for('/views/staff/docum/new_version.php?iddoc='); ?>" + iddoc;
 var options = {'idfile': iddoc, 'target_name': target_name, 'disabled': disabled, 'iduser': iduser, 'modificatedate': modificatedate, 'target_file': formData};

Comment: @BrandConstantin ¿probaste con el código como se indica en esta respuesta? ¿Cuál es el error que arroja?